# How can I delete AWS CLI configure access key and secret Access key of AWS CLI on command prompt?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I entered incorrect credentials on the secret access key and region name of the AWS CLI `configure` command on command prompt. I never found a way to change the secret access key.

I entered:

```
AWS Access Key 
AWS Secret Access Key
Default region name 
Default output format [None]:
```

I want to delete the `aws configure` of AWS CLI by using command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply run `aws configure` again and it will replace the existing values.

The information is stored in `~/.aws/credentials`, so you also have the option to manually edit that file, or even delete the file.